# Regex in Sudoers File?

Tags: regex, linux, sudo, sudoers

I've a regex and want to use it in a sudoers file. But I couldn't get it work.

```
\/test\/([0-9a-zA-Z\/]+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)+
```

I found that it must be

```
\\/test\\/([0-9a-zA-Z\/]+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)+
```

But I didn't know how to use the regex after /([...

Can I use the plus for 1 to n?
What must I escape? And how?

Comment: IIRC sudo does not support regexps, but only file globbing

Comment: Ok thank you! Than we use Cmnd_Alias      CUSTCHMOD = /bin/chmod * \\/test\\/*, ! /bin/chmod * *..*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sudo does not support regexps, but only file globbing.

See https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html#Wildcards

**Update:** Starting from 1.9.10 sudo also supports regular expressions: https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Regular_expressions

Comment: FYI: Starting with version 1.9.10, it is possible to use regular expressions for path names and command line arguments.